# Aegir different site folder from site name

Tags: multi-sites, aegir

When you create a new site in Aegir it creates the a directory using the sitename in the corresponding platform. So if the site name is `example.com` the path for the site will be `/var/aegir/platforms/platform_name/sites/example.com/`.

Is there a way to create the site in a different directory, like:  `/var/aegir/platforms/platform_name/sites/my_awsome_path/`?

Answer (score 1):

Using a different sitename would be your best option. You could then add an alias for the real sitename.

Comment: Thanks it works on normal environments (+1 for that).
But I tried on my environment and confuses the NLB and the SSL :(

Comment: Just the occurrence of the site name in a directory path is causing the problem? Then I would expect an alias to work fine for you.